# Why is this python code not working (Rock paper sisscors)?

Tags: python

Why is the if statement not working correctly, please help?
Dont know what's wrong.

```
import random

print("Rock, Paper, Scissors")
move = input("Type your move (R for Rock, P for Paper, and S for Scissors: ")
comp_move = random.choice(["R", "S", "P"])
print("Computer: " + comp_move)
def winner(comp_move, move):
    if move.upper == comp_move:
        print("It's A Tie")
    elif move.upper == "R" and comp_move == "S" or move.upper == "P" and comp_move == "R" \
            or move.upper == "S" and comp_move == "P":
        print("You Won :)")
    else:
        print("You Lose :(")
winner(comp_move, move)
```

Comment: Tell us more than just "it doesn't work". What does it do? Do you get an error message? Do you get nothing? Do you get an unexpected result? What do you expect when you run it?

Comment: Please *update the question* to elaborate on “not working”.  In your words, *what* is not working?  What was expected? What is occurring?

Comment: You are missing parenthesis around `.upper`. Next time it would be useful if you included more details about what exactly is "not working" or what error youre getting

Comment: Aside, the `elif` is all over the place and needs greater control.

Comment: For whatever input i give, it always says "You Lose :(".

Answer (score 2):

`upper` is a string method, not an attribute. So `'foo'.upper` is just a function, while `'foo'.upper()` is a string `FOO`.

```py
import random

WINNING_COMBINATIONS = {
    ('R', 'S'),
    ('P', 'R'),
    ('S', 'P'),
}

def winner(comp_move, move):
    move = move.upper()
    if move == comp_move:
        print("It's A Tie")
    elif (move, comp_move) in WINNING_COMBINATIONS:
        print("You Won :)")
    else:
        print("You Lose :(")

print("Rock, Paper, Scissors")
move = input("Type your move (R for Rock, P for Paper, and S for Scissors: ")
comp_move = random.choice(["R", "S", "P"])
print("Computer: " + comp_move)
winner(comp_move, move)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because `move.upper` is a method to call, to get the uppercase value you have to call it: `move.upper()` is the upper value.

So, applying to your code will become:

```
import random

print("Rock, Paper, Scissors")
move = input("Type your move (R for Rock, P for Paper, and S for Scissors: ")
comp_move = random.choice(["R", "S", "P"])
print("Computer: " + comp_move)
def winner(comp_move, move):
    if move.upper == comp_move:
        print("It's A Tie")
    elif move.upper() == "R" and comp_move == "S" or \
         move.upper() == "P" and comp_move == "R" or \
         move.upper() == "S" and comp_move == "P":

        print("You Won :)")
    else:
        print("You Lose :(")
winner(comp_move, move)
```

but you shouldn't call so many times the function, it's a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

As said in a previous answer you should use `.upper()` instead of `.upper` and you should add parenthesis in your if statements to make python understanding the priority of each part, like that:

```py
elif ((move.upper() == "R" and comp_move == "S") or (move.upper() == "P" and comp_move == "R") 
        or (move.upper() == "S" and comp_move == "P")):
```